# Does the FAA maintain pilot records from before 1998?

Tags: pilots, faa

I have held a PPL with an instrument rating since 1999, and I am desperate to continue, but I lost my logbook.

Is there any way to get records from the FAA about my total flying time?

I contacted my flight school, but they say they don't have a record of me, so they asked me to start over from 0 hours.

What can I do?

Comment: This is not necessarily a duplicate question, a different form can be used than was given in the other answer that provides a more comprehensive solution. AC_8060-68

Answer (score 1):

If you took a checkride the FAA has your 8710 (form you would have filled out) which will have your flight times and can be used as proof of time.  Follow [these steps](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/copy_of_certification_records/) to get your records.

You can search the [airman database](https://amsrvs.registry.faa.gov/airmeninquiry/).  My father's and grandfather's records are in there from the 1970s and 1980s.  This just lists certificates though, no times.

You can also [request a replacement certificate](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/airmen_services/).  If you are a PPL then they will send you one.  You'll need to do this anyway to get the new plastic card.  Also, no times...just a certificate...which prove that you have at least the minimum flight time required to hold the certificate.

Good luck.

Comment: thank you for you're reply I'm thinking of travelling to us to get back my records and look for flight school to do my PPL so i can do CFI CFII do you think its much peter that i come my self  for a week

Comment: do i need student visa to look for my lost records with FAA and apply for new airman certificate  i find i good rate ticket to orlando

Comment: can i do all that if i fly to FL Daytona with regular visa in order for me to replace my lost records and get new PPL certificate  is 10 days enough to solve all this matters

Answer (score 0):

If you hold a PPL and an instrument rating, then those are locked in by virtue of having earned them.  Surely the FAA has records confirming that you are a pilot with an instrument rating, but they may not have your total times from 20 years ago.

If by chance they do, they do not have records of your individual flights, so the evidence of what you would be reporting is lost.  You will likely have to start over with ***0 hours logged*** as a pilot with a PPL and instrument rating.

You may want to look into an electronic logbook service to prevent this from happening in the future.

Comment: thank you for you're reply I'm thinking of travelling to us to get back my records and look for flight school to do my PPL so i can do CFI CFII do you think its much peter that i come my self  for a week

Comment: can i do all that if i fly to FL Daytona with regular visa in order for me to replace my lost records and get new PPL certificate  is 10 days enough to solve all this matters

Comment: You already have your PPL.  No, 10 days will not be long enough to gather paperwork from a FSDO and then earn commercial, CFI, and CFII.

Since the last time you were here, there have been new laws created due to national security concerns (9/11, etc), so you would need to be approved through the alien flight student program at flightschoolcandidates.gov since you are not a us citizen or national.  Your chosen flight school should be able to guide you through this process.

Comment: you are right what i mean is 10 days to gather my lost documents and then fly back to my country and apply for visa ... regards my school they say you have to repeat every thing from scratch 0  and they ask for 70000 USD

Comment: Then I would say you should give your business to a different flight school.  A ppl and instrument is not "zero".

Comment: the problem is i have try many schools to get F1 visa  so i can practice CFI CFII MEI after words  F! is for  oversees student that also allow him to work as flight instructor and thats what I'm trying to do if u happened  to know any flight thats give F1 Visa please help me out

Answer (score 0):

At least since the 1970's (when I received my PPL), the FAA has had all pilot information stored and available on micro-fiche. I would expect the FAA has transferred, or at least be in the process of transferring the micro-fiche information to digital storage.

I would assume a request for a complete set of records includes print-outs of any remaining micro-fiche files and all digital storage in more recent years.

The FAA has a fee and specific form that needs to be filled out, the form is [AC_8060-68](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Form/AC_8060-68.pdf) The fee is 2 dollars for each search of records, .10 cents per printed page and an optional $10 for Certification of the record.

Comment: thank you for you're reply I'm thinking of travelling to us to get back my records and look for flight school to do my PPL so i can do CFI CFII do you think its much peter that i come my self  for a week

Comment: can i do all that if i fly to FL Daytona with regular visa in order for me to replace my lost records and get new PPL certificate  is 10 days enough to solve all this matters

Comment: Well, right now our politicians have shut down the govt for non essential services so nothing is getting done.Typical inquires to the govt such as receiving "N" numbers for experimental aircraft take 2 months. But it can all be done via mail. I would suggest using a friends US physical mail address for all return requests. But who knows, perhaps foreign addresses are common requests too.